# Identity in distributional sense, principal value $1/x$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, operator-theory, distribution-theory

> How to prove that
> $$
> T_{n}(\phi) =\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{r \le |x|} \frac{\cos(nx)}{x}\phi(x)\,\mathrm dx = \cos(nx)\ \operatorname {p.v.}\frac{1}{x},
> $$
> where $\phi$ belongs to $D(R)$ ($\phi$ is a test function).

Unfortunately, I don't know what to do with $\cos(nx)$ in the integral.

**I know that**
$$
\cos(nx)\ \operatorname {p.v.}\frac{1}{x}= \cos(nx) \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon \le |x|} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where $\phi$ belongs to $D(R)$.

I corrected my post.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $lim_{x\to 0}$? surely $\lim_{r\to 0}$? and are you saying the answer should be independent of $\phi$? (try $\phi=0$)

Comment: Of course $\lim_{r \to 0}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $fT$ for $f\in C^\infty$ and $T$ being a distribution is
$$
(fT)(\phi) := T(f\phi).
$$

What does this expand to when you have $f(x)=\cos nx$ and $T=\operatorname{pv}\frac1x$ defined by the following?
$$
T(\phi) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon \le |x|} \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you just applied the definition wrong. Recap- if $T\in \mathcal D'$  $f\in C^\infty,$  then $fT\in\mathcal D'$ is defined to be
$$ \langle fT,g\rangle := \langle T,fg\rangle \quad ( g\in \mathcal D)$$
In the case $f(x)=\cos(nx)$, $T\phi =\operatorname{pv}\frac1x\phi = \lim_{r\to0}\int_{|x|>r} \frac{\phi(x)}x dx,$ we see that
$$ \langle f\operatorname{pv}\frac1x,g\rangle = \langle \operatorname{pv}\frac1x,fg\rangle = \lim_{r\to0}\int_{|x|>r} \frac{\cos(nx)g(x)}x dx$$
and we see the product appears inside the integral.

Comment: hmm, ok and it works for $f(x) = cos(nx)$ because $cos(nx) \in C^{\infty}$?

Comment: @matm. Yes, $\cos(nx)\in C^\infty$ so $\cos(nx)\phi(x) \in C^\infty_c$ when $\phi\in C^\infty_c.$

Comment: @matm Exactly the above

Comment: then...that's very weird, my lecturer gave us this problem and he emphasized that we have to prove this... but this is a definition of a product of function which belongs to $C^{\infty}$ and a distribution...

Comment: Perhaps he meant for you to be absolutely sure of the definition of $fT$? ‍♂️

Comment: Probably yes :) thanks for help :)